# iOS bottom align a TableView in TableViewController (StoryBoard)

Tags: ios, uitableview

Is it possible to bottom align a `UITableView` when using the base `UITableViewController`? I want to do this for a Modal with a Partial Curl transition.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a `UITableViewController`, it automatically makes the tableview full screen, and that can't be changed.

However, if you don't need a `UITableViewController`, you can do this with a standard `UIViewController` and just set the size of the `UITableView` (in the storyboard, or in code as appropriate).

Comment: Yeah, I was starting to do this. I really just want static rows/groups. Using the StoryBoard UITableViewController manages that all for you. When attempting it this way, the table was not populated as it was in the StoryBoard.

Comment: Yeah, it's quite annoying that you can not use static tableview's without a UITableViewController so you have to use dynamic cells and sort it out in code.  It bugs me constantly, lol.